# How can I modify this formula to produce a result in all cases, rather than give errors?

Tags: excel

I have spreadsheet to record exam results for students. The results are entered in columns (one row of results per student) and I want to create a running average of the last three results. However, some students have missing data. An example is below:

```
 E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V ... Z
4.0 3.0 5.0 5.0     3.5
3.0 2.5 4.0 3.0     2.5
3.0     5.0 4.5     4.0
3.5     4.5         3.5
3.0 1.5 2.5 2.5     2.0
1.5 2.0 2.0 1.0     2.0
4.5 3.0 3.5 4.5     3.5
5.0 3.5 5.0 5.0     5.0
```

I have created a formula which works when the student has at least three pieces of data but fails when only one or two pieces is entered. The formula is:

```
=AVERAGE(LOOKUP(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(E3:Z3),COLUMN(E3:Z3)),{1,2,3}),COLUMN(E3:Z3),E3:Z3))
```

This is entered as an array formula. I realise I could do an IF checking for an error and put in additional code to cope with two pieces of data and then one but is there a quicker way?

I did try with AGGREGATE but couldn't get any answer.

Comment: Could you perhaps label your columns?

Comment: The columns of data run from column E to Column Z. I have updated the data to represent this.

Comment: Where do you enter the formula?

Comment: Sorry, each column contains a 'score' on a text between 0.1 and 12.0 - this allows us to compare different tests. If a cell is blank, it is because a student does not have a mark for that test. I want to calculate an average of the last thee items in the row. What I have ignores the blanks but doesn't work when a student only has two scores (such as the 4th row in the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `{1,2,3}` with `ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(3,COUNT(E3:Z3))))`

```
=AVERAGE(LOOKUP(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(E3:Z3),COLUMN(E3:Z3)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & MIN(3,COUNT(E3:Z3))))),COLUMN(E3:Z3),E3:Z3))
```

[image]

Comment: I thought you might know! Thanks.

Comment: That is really very clever.